# Property [categories] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\olshop\resources\views\backend\product\index.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

> **this is my Model**

```
//relation from model products to model categorys
public function categorys()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

**this is my controller**

```
 public function index()
{
    //controller buat manggil foreachnya
    $data['title'] ='Product';
    $data['page'] = 'Semua Product';
    $data['products'] = Product::all();
    return view('backend.product.index', $data);
}
```

**this is my **

```
                @foreach($products->categorys as $key => $value)
                <tr>
                    <!-- view bladenya  -->
                    <td>{{$key+1}}</td>
                    <td>{{$value->category_id->category}}</td>
                    <td>{{$value->product}}</td>
```

*I am trying to using $products->$categorys but its gone wrong*

Comment: It seems that you are not using standard table names. can you share your categorys schema and Model?

Comment: You have a spelling mistake. It should be spelled  `categories`. Laravel guesses the plural version of the table. You can specify to use a different name.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to do foreach loop on products and then for each single product do foreach loop on categories. Means:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
...
     @foreach($product->categories as $category)
        //You have list of categories for each product here
     @endforeach
...
@endforeach
```

Comment: It should be `$products` and not  `$data['products']` 

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code as per below:

Remove the duplicate function from the model `categorys()` and change your existing function name with `public function categories()`

In your controller change your line as below:

```
return view('backend.product.index')->with($data);
```

In your blade file you can access it as below:

```
@foreach($products->categories as $category)
  // Now You can access categories for each product here
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In your controller: 

public function index()
{
    $data['title'] ='Product';
    $data['page'] = 'Semua Product';
    $data['products'] = Product::all()->with('categorys');
    return view('backend.product.index, $data);
}

In your blade file :

@foreach($products as $product)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
        @if(!is_null($product->category))
           <td>{{ $product->category }}</td>
        @endif
        <td>{{ $product->product }}</td>
    </tr>
```